# Piecewise function not plotting

Tags: plotting

I have piecewise function  A which is defined as shown below. When I plot piecewise in Mathematica I could not able to see any points after  x=3.5, but If I evaluate the A I am getting value. I am bit confused and curious why it is happening? Am I using the piecewise function properly?

```
z1 = 1;
z2 = 2;
z3 = 3;
L = 4;
a1 = -0.0664623 Cos[1.52648 x] + 0.0664621 Cosh[1.52648 x] + 
  0.0736429 Sin[1.52648 x] - 0.0736415 Sinh[1.52648 x] 
a2 = 0.0706263 Cos[1.52648 (-1 + x)] - 
  0.0012975 Cosh[1.52648 (-1 + x)] + 
  0.0696575 Sin[1.52648 (-1 + x)] - 0.0317435 Sinh[1.52648 (-1 + x)] 
a3 = 0.0727183 Cos[1.52648 (-2 + x)] - 
  0.0727174 Cosh[1.52648 (-2 + x)] - 0.413845 Sin[1.52648 (-2 + x)] + 
  0.267041 Sinh[1.52648 (-2 + x)] 
a4 = -0.410217 Cos[1.52648 (-3 + x)] + 
  0.410216 Cosh[1.52648 (-3 + x)] + 0.585447 Sin[1.52648 (-3 + x)] - 
  0.192384 Sinh[1.52648 (-3 + x)] 
A = Piecewise[{{a1, x <= z1}, {a2, z1 <= x <= z2}, {a3, 
    z2 <= x <= z3}, {a4, x >= z3}}]
Plot[A, {x, 0, L}]
```

Comment: `Plot` has a lot of hidden calculating going on. Part of this tries to decide what range to plot. If you change your code to `Plot[A, {x, 0, L},PlotRange->All]` it will show you everything out to 4. You can look up `PlotRange` to see how to give it even more precise instructions.

Comment: @acoustics in the last position put `{a4, True}` instead  `{a4, x >= z3}` and take `L=5` to check difference.

Answer (score 3):

I have done some modifications on your code such that you can obtain your desired plot. If you want to have a different region in the plot you can change minX,maxX, minY and maxY values.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

z1 = 1;
z2 = 2;
z3 = 3;
L = 4;

a1[x_] := -0.0664623 Cos[1.52648 x] + 0.0664621 Cosh[1.52648 x] +    0.0736429 Sin[1.52648 x] - 0.0736415 Sinh[1.52648 x];
a2[x_] := 0.0706263 Cos[1.52648 (-1 + x)] - 0.0012975 Cosh[1.52648 (-1 + x)] + 0.0696575 Sin[1.52648 (-1 + x)] - 0.0317435 Sinh[1.52648 (-1 + x)];
a3[x_] := 0.0727183 Cos[1.52648 (-2 + x)] - 0.0727174 Cosh[1.52648 (-2 + x)] - 0.413845 Sin[1.52648 (-2 + x)] + 0.267041 Sinh[1.52648 (-2 + x)];
a4[x_] := -0.410217 Cos[1.52648 (-3 + x)] + 0.410216 Cosh[1.52648 (-3 + x)] + 0.585447 Sin[1.52648 (-3 + x)] - 0.192384 Sinh[1.52648 (-3 + x)];

A[x_] := Piecewise[{
{a1[x], x <= z1},
{a2[x], z1 <= x <= z2},
{a3[x], z2 <= x <= z3},
{a4[x], x >= z3}
}];


minX = 0;
maxX = L;

minY = -0.5;
maxY = A[L];

Plot[A[x], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> {{minX, maxX}, {minY, maxY}}]
```

When you run the code, you obtain

[image]